# ASP.Net Core MVC Route issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

I have an MVC application that when I browse to root (http://localhost:5000) when debugging it attempts to load index.html rather than taking me to {HomeController}/{Index}

If I build the application into a Docker image the route work as expected

All other Routes work as expected but this one, I can't see any reference to index.html anywhere in the project.

My route mapping (Startup.cs):

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

My views are setup as default:

Views 
-Home 
--Index.cshtml

Comment: Please clarify, Actually your controller is calling : /Home/Index because your method is called Index which mean : go to Home Folder (under Views) and open Index.cshtml file. Do you want or expect another behavior ?

Comment: Yes this is what i expect, but its actually loading /index.html which doesn't exist.

Comment: Okay, add a breakpoint in the return statement in : Home/Index and see if the method is called

Comment: I've tried that, it doesn't hit the breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a route attribute on the controller ? if yes, then remove It and try again because when you use route attribute all your defined routes in UseMvc and  UseMvcWithDefaultRoute() will be ignored [Source.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1#mixed-routing)

Another solution is to add a route attribute before your index method :

```
 [Route("")]
 [Route("Home")]
 [Route("Home/Index")]
 public IActionResult Index()
 {
    return View();
 }
```

Comment: I'v tried both with and without your route attributes and am still getting the same result. One thing i have noticed is when i build my application into a docker container and run it the routes work as they should, browsing to http://localhost:5000 takes me to the HomeControllers Index Method. I've updated my question to reflect this